# Efficient way to update multiple records with independent values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have the following (overly db expensive) method:

```
    def reorder_area_routes_by_demographics!
      self.area_routes.joins(:route).order(self.demo_criteria, :proximity_rank).readonly(false).each_with_index do |area_route, i|
        area_route.update_attributes(match_rank: i)
      end
    end
```

But this results in an UPDATE query for each area_route. Is there a way to do this in one query?

--Edit--

Final solution, per coreyward suggestion:

```
def reorder_area_routes_by_demographics!
  sorted_ids = area_routes.joins(:route).order(self.demo_criteria, :proximity_rank).pluck(:'area_routes.id')
  AreaRoute.update_all [efficient_sort_sql(sorted_ids), *sorted_ids], {id: sorted_ids}
end

def efficient_sort_sql(sorted_ids, offset=0)
  offset.upto(offset + sorted_ids.count - 1).inject('match_rank = CASE id ') do |sql, i|
    sql << "WHEN ? THEN #{id} "
  end << 'END'
end
```

Comment: If new data you update the table with is in the database, then you can run a query on db to update all values in `area_route` in one transaction. It will be faster than updating rows one by one. I'm not familiar with Ruby so if you can translate the statement to SQL or tell the logic, then I can write you that SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to do a similar task: updating the sort positions of a bevy of records according to their order in params. You might need to refactor or incorporate this differently to accomodate the scopes you're applying, but I think this will send you in the right direction.

```
def efficient_sort_sql(sortable_ids, offset = 1)
  offset.upto(offset + sortable_ids.count - 1).reduce('position = CASE id ') do |sql, i|
    sql << "WHEN ? THEN #{i} "
  end << 'END'
end

Model.update_all [efficient_sort_sql(sortable_ids, offset), *sortable_ids], { id: sortable_ids }
```

`sortable_ids` is an array of integers representing the ids of each object. The resulting SQL looks something like this:

```
UPDATE pancakes SET position = CASE id WHEN 5 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 2 WHEN 4 THEN 3 WHEN 1 THEN 4 WHEN 2 THEN 5 WHERE id IN (5,3,4,1,2);
```

This is, ugliness aside, a pretty performant query and (at least in Postgresql) will either fully succeed or fully fail.